# Jovo Alexa: jovo deploy says Trigger settings for the lambda is invalid

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

I am creating an Alexa skill using JOVO framework. I have completed the following steps on `Amazon Alexa` console:

1. Created a new skill in AWS Alexa console
2. Created a function in Lambda console
3. Under endpoints of the skill added the `Lambda arn`.
4. Added an Alexa Skill Kit trigger in the above lambda function and added the Skill ID
5. Saved endpoints successfully.

Local setup:

`$ jovo new WeatherService`
`$ cd WeatherService`
`$ code .`
`$ ask init`
  selected `ask defualt`. Logged in through IAM console in browser
$ jovo build --platform alexaSkill

Up to this everything works fine. So I went on to deploy the skill by the following command:

`$ jovo deploy`

When the Lambda was trying to deploy, I get the following message:

> The trigger setting for the Lambda
>             arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:880731272882:function:MyWeatherTeller is
>   invalid

Out of curiosity, I ran the same command `$jovo deploy` and this time it is a different error message:

> askApiUpdateSkill:Resource not found

What I am doing wrong?

Below are screenshots of the console setup:

**Function setup:**
[image]

Skill endpoint setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a newly created Jovo project, the `$ jovo deploy` command creates a new Alexa Skill project.

This new project has a different Skill ID than the Skill project you've created by hand. This is why your trigger (which only accepts 1 Skill ID if verification is enabled) is complaining.

If you don't want to create a new Skill project with the deploy command, you can also add the current Skill ID to your `project.js` ([learn more here](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/project-js)) file:

```
alexaSkill: {
    nlu: 'alexa',
    skillId: 'yourSkillId',
},
```

Then run the two commands again:

```
$ jovo build
$ jovo deploy
```

Comment: Works! Only one doubt. In one of my previous Skills, I didn't have to add the `skillId` in `project.js `. I just use `jovo deploy -t lambda` for whatever changes I make in my code. Is this a kind of change made recently?

Comment: If you create a fresh new Skill with the `jovo deploy` command, the new Skill ID is saved to the `platforms/alexaSkill/.ask/config` file. If you want to use a different Skill ID, you either have to change it there or add it to the `project.js` file (which writes into the ask config file during `jovo build`